# How to Auto-Check checkboxes using jsTree with the checkbox/html_data plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Using jsTree, I am trying to auto-check certain nodes based on ID. I am using the HTML_DATA and Checkbox plugin.

```
$("#ItemTree").jstree({ 
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui" ],
});
```

My UL

```
<div id="ItemTree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="37" href="#37">This item should auto check.</a>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

How can I auto check id="37"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found on [jsTeee site](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox)

```
<div id="ItemTree">
  <ul>
    <li class="jstree-checked">
      <a id="37" href="#37">This item should auto check.</a>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class `jstree-clicked` as follows:

```
<div id="ItemTree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="37" href="#37" class="jstree-clicked">This item should auto check.</a>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```